# Can't find MasterCategoryList in ExchangeWebServices

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to setup a new category and add it to an appointment, but when trying to follow this: http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/28/Working-with-the-Master-Category-List%E2%80%93EWS-edition.aspx I get: `'MasterCategoryList' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

I'm using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices version 14.0.0.0.

I assume something's changed in the service since that article was posted, but I can't find anything useful in the docs :\ can anyone out there help!? :)

Comment: What context are you using it in ? have you rewritten it at all ? The error itself isn't a EWS error it failing at VS Syntax level.

Comment: @GlenScales yes, it seems to be missing from the API, rather than any runtime problem. This is in a C# command-line app, and I'm not even able to compile it, because it doesn't seem to be there in the API. Doesn't get any simpler! :\

Comment: The MasterCategoryList isn't in the Managed API that is something Henning built so if you look at the download project include with hist post he has the classes you need to include in your project. In the Managed API you use the UserConfiguration classes (but look at the methods in hist classes this is what he is using)

Comment: @GlenScales Ah! Thank you thank you! I didn't even think it was custom code! That's the answer, isn't it? Post as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MasterCategoryList isn't in the Managed API that is something Henning built so if you look at the download project include with hist post he has the classes you need to include in your project. In the Managed API you use the UserConfiguration classes.